# How to insert data in desired column in sqlite3?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect('Stores.db')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS checkit
            (
            number integer,
            even integer,
            odd integer          
            )""")

conn.commit()
conn.close()
n=int(input("Input any integer"))

if n%2==0:
    conn=sqlite3.connect('Stores.db')
    c=conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO checkit VALUES(:a,:b,:c)",{
                'a':n,
                'b':n
                })

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

else:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Stores.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO checkit VALUES(:a,:b,:c)", {
        'a': n,
        'c': n
   })

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

This is my code. I was trying to store number in 'number' column, even number in 'even' column and odd number in 'odd' column of 'checkit' table of database 'Srores.db'. But I am getting `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 3.` error when I enter even number and `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 2.` error when I enter odd number. 
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The number of columns and value placeholders in the SQL statements must match the number values being provided.  In this case, no columns are specified - meaning all columns must be populated, three value placeholders are specified but only two values are provided.

Change the SQL to accept only the columns being populated

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO checkit (number, even) VALUES(:a,:b)",{
            'a':n,
            'b':n
            })
```

Or provide a value for the "missing" value

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO checkit (number, even, odd) VALUES(:a,:b,:c)",{
            'a':n,
            'b':n,
            'c':0
            })
```